# Visual (apparently) bug with ComplexConjugate in FeynCalc

Tags: physics, feyncalc

When I use ComplexConjugate in Feyncalc, if there are repeated indices in its argument, a visual bug occurs. The most minimal example would be:

```
ComplexConjugate[Contract[GA[\[Mu]].MT[\[Mu], \[Nu]].GA[\[Nu]]]]
```

for which I get the awful $\gamma^{\$\text{AL(\$30)}}.\gamma^{\$\text{AL(\$30)}}$, or another 'random' number in place of the 30.

The same thing happens without the Contract, but it only occurs with the use of ComplexConjugate.

How can I solve it?

Comment: Calc @ ComplexConjugate[Contract[GA[\[Mu]].MT[\[Mu], \[Nu]].GA[\[Nu]]]]  gives 4.

Comment: I don't really know what a "visual bug" is ... . Mathematically it is not a bug. This kind of renaming is necessary for certain more complicated operations in order to avoid getting wrong results. I think I introduced this for calculations involving tensor reductions and Schouten identities.

Comment: Although FeynCalc documentation usually lags behind recent development, this case is actually covered (https://feyncalc.github.io/FeynCalcBook/ref/ComplexConjugate.html), cf. "Since FeynCalc 9.3 ComplexConjugate will automatically rename dummy indices."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SetOptions[ComplexConjugate, FCRenameDummyIndices -> False]
```

will not rename the repeated (dummy) indices.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm sorry about calling it a bug, my understanding of these things is less then minimal. Knowing now, from your comment, that this relabeling is useful for some computations I might actually get used to it.